# Are the words "soul" and "spirit" synonymous?

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “spirit” and “soul”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40511/difference-between-spirit-and-soul)

Is there any difference between the two? Or do both refer to the part of body that is believed to exist after you die?

Comment: The Wiktionary entry for [spirit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spirit) reads: _"The undying essence of a human. The [soul](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soul)."_ So, yes.

Comment: Also, a dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40511/difference-between-spirit-and-soul and related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72042/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-soul

Comment: Doesn't the answer to such a question vary across various philosophies?

Comment: This question is really more about religion and philosophy than language. You're looking for a technical definition of these words, not a conventional definition.

Comment: @Jay: Seems you know better what I am looking for.

Comment: I believe that the standard Christian answer for this is that the soul consists of the mind and the spirit.  So the spirit specifically excludes the mind.  I have no written source for this; it's simply what a priest told me once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Soul* is a Germanic word; *spirit* is a Latin word. They are used synonymously in some contexts, but each has its own quirks, like any pair of putative synonyms.

*Spirit* comes from Latin *spiritus*, which means 'breath', and is therefore symbolic of life of all sort, including human life, and also of the state of being alive.

If you stop breathing, your *spirit* leaves you. Very straightforward body metaphor.

The OED says, of *spirit*,

> The earlier English uses of *spirit* are mainly derived from passages in the Vulgate, in which *spiritus* is employed to render Gr. *pneuma* and Heb. *ruax* (both meaning 'breath'). The translation of these words by *spirit* (or one of its variant forms) is common to all English versions of the Bible from Wyclif onwards.

*Soul* is common Germanic, and is generally used in situations where today we would use words like *personality, character, mind* -- or *spirit*, to refer to the way people behave and our intuitions about "what they're **really** like".

So, if one is sufficiently abstract, yes, they **can** be synonymous. But beware of specific uses, which are highly idiomatic.

Comment: +1 for both showing where the words came from, and for the last paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are sometimes synonymous. But there are many cases in which they aren't.

For instance, if you're talking about morality, the concept of right and wrong, "*soul*" is suitable.

As in,

```
He has no soul.
```

On the other hand, when one is talking about strong dedication or loyalty, "*spirit*" is used:

```
the team spirit
```

The mood of a period:

```
the spirit of the sixties
```

There are also expressions like "I am with you **in spirit**" where "*soul*" can't be substituted.

Comment: Good examples. As an aside, there's also a difference between _soul music_ and _spiritual music_.

Comment: True @J.R. There were a lot of other things I wanted to cite, but I guess these (and yours) would be enough

Comment: Also, "a soul" can be used as a metonym to mean "a person" (as in "there wasn't a soul around"), whereas "spirit" used like that implies a ghost.

Comment: Yes, that too. And a "generous spirit" etc.

Comment: As @J.R. touched on, *Soul* has a very different meaning in AAVE, roughly akin to "black" or "blackness". Spirit doesn't have this connotation.

Comment: I think what you're really saying here is that "soul" and "spirit" each have multiple definitions, some of which are synonyous and some of which are not. Life if we say, "Humans have an immortal soul", and "Bob likes soul food", we are using two different definitions of the word.

Comment: @Jay: _"each have multiple definitions, some of which are synonyous and some of which are not..."_ Bingo. Well-said. We could almost put that in the FAQ, under a special heading for synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

No. 
Soul is supposed to be a part of human body. 
Spirit is a supernatural being external to the human body.